# How to populate datepicker's input element with its defaultDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is there any way to populate [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)'s `input` element with its `defaultDate`?

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

**JS**

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    defaultDate: +7
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k9fdw2ub/

I want users to see the default date in the `input` element itself, not just in the pop-up calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for you.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    defaultDate: +7
});

 $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', 'today');
// $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', 7); If you wanna set date from future 7days from current date use this
```

Comment: Should I put it *after* the `$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    defaultDate: +7
});`?

Comment: Yes @Frozen heart

Comment: Can I somehow pass it `+7` as well?

Comment: Yes you can @frozen

Answer (score 2):

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k9fdw2ub/6/)

Try below code

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({

    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
});

$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', 'today + 7');
```

Answer (score 1):

By using set `setDate` you can achieve it.

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Comment: Can I somehow pass it `+7` as well?